# Desktop freezes when pressed minimized button in maximized windows in unity

Tags: 11.10, unity

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 x64.
Ubuntu freezes when I pressed minimize button when in maximized windows but minimize button works well in non-maximized(restored) windows.
Also, the unity sidebar doesn't shows occasionally when hovered in left.

Answer (score 3):

i encounter this problem my self on both of my computer, the problems occur when i upgrade the motherboard of both of the PCs. Both system are not identical, one is AMD pc and one is Intel pc. So it confuses me why the problem occurs cause im not doing a clean install, i just use the same previous hardisk directly on the systems. I just find the solutions yesterday when i use live cd on the system, it seems that the configurations are messed up because of maybe the previous configuration of ubuntu. So this is the solutions i did:

Solution 1. Just create a new administator / user account. Your new account should work as it should. No unity freezing when minimize from a maximized window.

Solution 2. Use either gnome shell or live cd and browse to ur directory using root.

gksudo nautilus

browse to your home directory:
please enable hidden files from View option first

delete .compiz-1 folder
delete .compiz-1 & dconf inside .config folder
delete .gconf folder (or maybe just the compiz folder inside apps inside the folder.. im not sure cause i just delete .gconf folder directly)

lastly restart Ubuntu, and log in.

I hope this will solved your problem

--William, Ubuntu User Malaysia

Answer (score 1):

While William Peetal's answer addresses the issue properly, you can also use Workspace Switcher as a temporary solution, i.e., to get out of the current freeze state, like when you have to save your file before restart.

Just use shortcut keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Right/Left Arrow</kbd> to switch between Workspaces. Press this combination of keys until you get to your Workspace and you will see that the window is not frozen any more.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when desktop icons are switched off. Go into `gnome-tweak-tool` , select 'Desktop' and turn on 'Icons on Desktop.' You can unselect all the checkboxes if you like, but make sure 'Icons on Desktop' is selected.